# Spring Integration + Spring Batch: the job doesn`t stop

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I want to read file from ftp server, then save it into local repository and delete from server, run the job that read file, find one record on DB, change one parameter and save it.

What is going wrong: job doesn't finish; increments salary and saves employee many times.

Spring Integration configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer(DefaultFtpSessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(sessionFactory);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(remoteDirectory);
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "fileInputChannel", poller = @Poller(cron = "*/5 * * * * ?"))
    public FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource ftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer) throws Exception {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource messageSource = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(fileSynchronizer);
        messageSource.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        messageSource.setLocalDirectory(new File(localDirectory));
        messageSource.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fileInputChannel")
    public FileWritingMessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler() {
        FileWritingMessageHandler messageHandler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(localDirectory));
        messageHandler.setOutputChannelName("jobLaunchRequestChannel");
        return messageHandler;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "jobLaunchRequestChannel", outputChannel = "jobLaunchingGatewayChannel")
    public JobLaunchRequest jobLaunchRequest(File file) throws IOException {
        String[] content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8").split("\\s+");
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("filename", file.getAbsolutePath())
                .addString("id", content[0]).addString("salary", content[1])
//                .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .toJobParameters();
        return new JobLaunchRequest(increaseSalaryJob, jobParameters);
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "jobLaunchingGatewayChannel")
    public JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway(SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher) {
        JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway = new JobLaunchingGateway(jobLauncher);
        jobLaunchingGateway.setOutputChannelName("finish");
        return jobLaunchingGateway;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "finish")
    public void finish() {
        System.out.println("FINISH");
    }
}
```

Spring Batch configuration:

```
 @Bean
    public Job increaseSalaryJob(CustomJobListener listener, Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("increaseSalaryJob")
                .preventRestart()
                .listener(listener)
                .start(step1)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(ItemReader<Employee> reader) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .<Employee, Employee> chunk(1)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<Employee> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters[id]}") Integer id) {
        log.info("reader");
        return () -> employeeService.get(id);
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemProcessor<Employee, Employee> processor() {
        log.info("processor");
        return employee -> {
            log.info(employee.getName() + " had salary " + employee.getSalary());
            Integer salary = employee.getSalary() + 1;
            employee.setSalary(salary);
            log.info(employee.getName() + " have salary " + employee.getSalary());

            return employee;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<Employee> writer() {
        log.info("writer");
        return employees -> {
            for (Employee employee : employees) {
                try {
                    employeeService.update(employee);
                    log.info(employee.getName() + " updated with salary " + employee.getSalary());
                } catch (ValidationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(transactionManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean) throws Exception {
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return jobLauncher;
    }
```

I will be glad of any help.

Comment: Does you reader returns `null` at some point? If you run a job for single Id, a simple tasklet is enough, no need for a chunk-oriented tasklet with a single input record and a chunkSize=1.

Comment: thanks Mahmoud, it helps me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that your reader returns `null` at some point. This is how the step interprets that there is no more data to process and exits (which in turn will stop the surrounding job if there are no more steps to run).

That said, I see the input of your chunk-oriented step is a single `id`. For this use case, a simple tasklet is enough, no need for a chunk-oriented tasklet with a single input record and `chunkSize=1`.