# Misunderstanding with JobLaunchRequest

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

this is my previous question: [Spring Integration + Spring Batch: the job doesn`t stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60533651/spring-integration-spring-batch-the-job-doesnt-stop).

Project works good with annotation configuration, but I want the same on xml config :)

xml configuration:

```
    <int:service-activator input-channel="fileInputChannel"
                           method="fileWritingMessageHandler"
                           output-channel="jobLaunchRequestChannel">
        <bean class="service.impl.IntegrationServiceImpl"/>
    </int:service-activator>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="jobLaunchRequestChannel"
                           method="jobLaunchRequest"
                           output-channel="jobLaunchingGatewayChannel">
        <bean class="service.impl.IntegrationServiceImpl"/>
    </int:service-activator>

    <batch-int:job-launching-gateway request-channel="jobLaunchingGatewayChannel"
                                     reply-channel="finish"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="finish"
                           ref="integrationServiceImpl"
                           method="finishJob">
    </int:service-activator>
```

IntegrationConfiguration.java:

```
    @Bean
    public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(defaultFtpSessionFactory);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(remoteDirectory);
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "fileInputChannel", poller = @Poller(cron = "*/5 * * * * ?"))
    public FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource ftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer) throws Exception {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource messageSource = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(fileSynchronizer);
        messageSource.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        messageSource.setLocalDirectory(new File(localDirectory));
        messageSource.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());
        return messageSource;
    }
```

IntegrationServiceImpl:

```
    @Override
    public FileWritingMessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler() {
        FileWritingMessageHandler messageHandler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(storageDirectory));
        messageHandler.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
        messageHandler.setFileNameGenerator(message -> {
            Long timestamp = new Date().getTime();
            log.info(timestamp);
            return "test_" + timestamp;
        });
        return messageHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public JobLaunchRequest jobLaunchRequest(File file) throws IOException {
//    public JobLaunchRequest jobLaunchRequest(FileWritingMessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler) throws IOException {
        String[] content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8").split("\\s+");
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("filename", file.getAbsolutePath())
                .addString("id", content[0])
                .addString("salary", content[1])
                .toJobParameters();
        log.info(jobParameters);
        return new JobLaunchRequest(increaseSalaryJob, jobParameters);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishJob() {
        log.info("Job finished");
    }
```

As you can see this xml config like previous post annotation config, BUT i have an error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method jobLaunchRequest(org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler) cannot be found on type service.impl.IntegrationServiceImpl
```

Why i can't use jobLaunchRequest(File)? And if i need to use jobLaunchRequest(FileWritingMessageHandler) how can I operate with file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jobLaunchRequest()` method definitely has to be with a `File` argument because that is indeed what produced as a payload in the reply message from the `FileWritingMessageHandler`.

Your `<int:service-activator input-channel="fileInputChannel"
                           method="fileWritingMessageHandler">` definition is wrong.

Since you would like to use a `FileWritingMessageHandler` as a service, you need to consider to use an `<int-file:outbound-gateway>` instead.

The `service-activator` is for calling POJO methods. Since `FileWritingMessageHandler` is a `MessageHandler` implementation it has to be used in the `<service-activator>` directly from the `ref` attribute without any `method` attribute usage.